# No puedo mezclar datos de distintos tipos

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class Clase1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String texto="mi mama me mima mucho";
    char letraBuscada=texto.charAt(0);      //cambiar el numero segun la letra buscada
    String[] textoSeparado = texto.split("m");  //cambiar la letra para generar la cantidad buscada
    int veces=0;                    //no puedo vincular estas dos variables para 
                        //modificar un solo dato y que me resuelva el problema.
    
        for(String letraCantidad : textoSeparado) {
            veces++;
        }
        System.out.println("Para el texto "+texto);
        System.out.print("La letra "+letraBuscada+" aparece "+(veces-1)+" veces");
    }
}
```

Necesito hacer esto en java cambiando solo un dato y me dice que no puedo mezclar `char` con `String[]`.
Les dejo mi codigo, que si bien funciona, hay que poner dos datos y no uno solo.

Lo que yo busco es que el codigo me cuente las letras de la frase con solo poner el digito en el charAt().

Cambie char int String pero no puedo mezclar datos de distintos tipos.
Quise hacer `String[] textoSeparado = texto.split(letraBuscada);` y por supuesto, no me dejo.

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que buscas, podes ser más específico? probe tu código y no muestra error

Comment: Por favor cuida la redacción y edición de la pregunta. No se entiende qué es lo que quieres lograr. Pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu problema. Gracias.

Comment: Por otro lado, creo que el `split` no te va a servir para el problema de fondo

Comment: tendrias que hacer un cast del tipo char to String para que puedas usar el metodo split   texto.split(String.valueOf(letraBuscada)); pero pareciera que te piden un método con dos parámetros un texto y una letra , especifica mejor tu problema

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Clase1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dato = 0;  // busca la letra "m". 
 
        String texto = "mi mama me mima mucho";
        char letraBuscada = texto.charAt( dato );

           // convertir el texto en un array de char.    
        char[] textoSeparado = texto.toCharArray();  
        int veces = 0;   
           
           // recorrer array y si hay coincidencia aumentar "veces"
        for( char letra : textoSeparado) {
            if( letra == letraBuscada ) {
                veces++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "Para el texto " + texto );

           // acá cambié (veces) por veces para que de correcto
        System.out.print( "La letra " + letraBuscada + " aparece " + veces + " veces" ); 
    }
}
```